# Find neighboring elements of matrix element

Tags: python, math, matrix

I need to find local maximum of matrix. I use function `check()` to check whether current element is the biggest among its neighbors. Here is my code, for some elements it works, but for some doesnt:

```
A = [[6,5,4,1],
     [0,2,7,1],
     [2,4,6,9]]
def check(row,column):
    elem = A[row][column]
    for i in range((row-1), (row+2)):
        for j in range((column-1), (column+2)):
            if (i>=0 and i < n) and (j>=0 and j < n) and (row != i and column != j):
                if A[i][j] > elem:
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: Try to use `numpy` instead of list.

Comment: It's a test algorithm. I'm gonna write it for Javascript. But before test it in Python

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to check is if the current element is the max, you can modify your function like this. I added a sample matrix A.

```
A=[[1,2,3],[1,4,3],[4,3,4]]
def check(row,column):
    elem = A[row][column]
    for i in range((row-1), (row+2)):
        for j in range((column-1), (column+2)):
            try:
                if i > -1 and j > -1 and A[i][j] > A[row][column]:
                    return False
            except IndexError:
                pass
    return True
#Is 2 at (0,1) max?
print check(0,1)
#Is 3 at (1,2) max?
print check(1,2)
#Is 4 at (1,1) max?
print check(1,1)
#Is 4 at (2,2) max?
print check(1,1)
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
True
```

By catching and ignoring IndexError, you can avoid checking if you are out of bounds in your looping (seems that's what you are attempting to do with your check using n, which you haven't defined.) Also I am not considering if the values are equal since you are only interested if the current is max or not. If you need to do something different when you are at current element you can check for i,j equals to row, column respectively and put custom checks)

Comment: I attached my sample matrix. You algortihm gives wrong result even for [0][0] element

Comment: @Andrew, looks like you do not want circular lookup(col 0 and col 3 are not neighbours). I modified my answer to ignore negative indices.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that you arent trying to test places that are not part your 2-D array. if you try to test things in this manor not only are you speeding up the process because you are cutting off branches that you need to check but you are also speeding up the process of figuring out if the element place you are currently checking is or is not the max
if you are not using a 2-D array attempt to do so it may make the process easier

Comment: Please consider reformatting or somehow rewriting your answer. It *is* unreadable in it's current state.